# fabric.js object selection mouse down

Tags: fabricjs

I want to know if there is a way to select correct object when we click on it to change the color.

I have two angular triangles on my canvas but when i click on it i can only select one because the bounding box is squared.

I use :

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e))
```

But i am unable to select the triangle i want only 1 is selectable due to the size of bounding box.

Thank you for your help

I want to change the color of the triangle when i click on it. Example if i click on the red triangle this triangle come green. If i click on the black triangle this one comes blue. But its impossible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e){
var triangle = e.target;
if(triangle)
triangle.setFill('your color');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
perPixelTargetFind: true // prevents clicking on bounding-box around shape from selecting it
```

to the triangles